# How to get second or third 'part' of user input? C++

Tags: c++, iostream

User input is:

```
0 1 4 5
```

How can i get 0 and save it to a integer, then how can i get 4 and save it to a integer?

Situation 2:

User input is:

```
0B11B3B76B
```

How can i save all of them (seperatly) into array (type String)?

I know it's easy question for some of You, but thats my first day in C++, and I have to get this done. .NET forever!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Look into [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) and use the `int` type and the [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) type.

Comment: Yes, std:cin, but it will save whole 0 1 4 5, but i want only ex. 4. That's what I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to iterate though each byte of the input string, extracting each digit and casting it as an integer to your array, this helps if you know the size of the input string or the string is a fixed or has a maximum length.

Something like:

```
char myStr[12] = "0123456789";

int myArray[12];
int intCh;

for (intCh = 0; intCh < 12; intCh++) {
   /* Look for the \0 byte that terminates the string. */
   if (myStr[intCh] == '\0')
       break;

   /* We need to cast the char to an int as we store it in the
    * array something like this.
    */
   myArray[intCh] = (int) myStr[intCh];
}
```

I hope that helps, I haven't coded in C or C++ for a while but it should give you some pointers...heh, get it? Pointers!

Good luck.

Just to add, your question confused me slightly since you open by saying you want to cast int to char, then you end by saying you want to do the opposite and convert integer types to string.

To do that you'd use the reverse, you'd take the members of your array of integers and cast them to (char) on the assignment:

```
myStr[intCh] = (char) myArray[intCh];
```

Or some such thing ;)